# If indian currency is selected, show only "India" in country list for billing address

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I would like for only "India" to appear in the country list for the billing address when a user selects "Indian" for the currency.

How can I do this?

I am using Magento 1.9.3.9

Comment: by saying user select indian currency, did you created a store for indian currency ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new store view "India" then you can set currency = INR,  default and allowed countries = India only from the country list in "India" store view.